# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow runs multiple times

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, content-type

I have a site was created based on a customised Site Template (created by using Save Site as Template); The template has a customised List, a workflow(via List Content Type, Global reusable associated to the parent Site Content Type) runs on both "when a new item is created" and "when an item is changed".

I have noticed on Workflow Status page, the same workflow listed 5 times under the Completed Workflows with exactly the same starting and ending time. This only happens when the item is newly created, thereafter workflow runs just once as expected.

I have tried to create a new list and added the same Site ContentType, then the workflow in question runs as expected, ie once when new item is created...

I also have deleted all orphan WorkFlow Status columns on the List, funny eunough the number of duplicated orphan Workflow Status columns on the list matches the number of times the Workflow runs. But no lucky, Workflow still runs 5 times.

Just wonder what had caused this, I was hope to use powershell to find any duplicated ItemAdd events on either the SPList or the List ContentType, but no luck! Only Event Reciever I have managed to find on SPList was something to do with TaxonomyItems...

Open to any suggestions or idea in finding the cause of this issue.

Comment: Does your problem persist after you add a 1 minute pause at the start of your workflow? That pause fixes some "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information" errors that pop up, so it's good practice regardless.

Comment: @AronFoster, Thanks for your suggestions. However the workflow doesn't hit any error at all.

Comment: Correction! I have managed to find multiple ItemAdded Event Receivers on the List. After removing duplated event receivers on the List using PowserShell, Workflow is working as normal. However this doesn't solve my problem because once I saved the Site as a Site Template and create a new site using this Template I am back to square one. List in the newly created Site had 2 ItemAdded and 2 ItemUpdated event receivers. I guess Sharepoint creates these event receiver when creating the new site... Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does your problem persist after you add a 1 minute pause at the start of your workflow?

Comment: @AronFoster, No I didn't. but I have decided not to use this technique, just because of the unpredictable behavier I have experienced so far. Thanks anyway.